# how to get file with changed name in application runtime on OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, file, save

i'm writing application that save file with name as document title typed by user. When user clicked save, then document is saved as `documentTitle.txt`, but when user change document title and click save, then document is saved as `newDocumentTitle.txt`.

The question is: Is possible to get `uniqueIdentifier` for edited file something like zbookmark`or`documentID` on the disk?

thank you for help.

Comment: are you asking any file identifier from system for already existing file , or to generate uniqueIndentifier programmatically

Comment: I need to find file identifier (unique). The answer is `bookmarkDataWithOptions:includingResourceValuesForKeys:relativeToURL:error:` of `NSURL class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to localize file by its unique identifier?

Need to use method of `NSURL` Class.

`bookmarkDataWithOptions:includingResourceValuesForKeys:relativeToURL:error:`